# Why I get this strange result: [BLOB - ...]?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my database schema:

```
Post:
id
title
body
date

Tag:
id
title

Post_Tag:
id
id_post
id_tag

Comment:
id
id_post
body
date
```

and this is my query:

```
SELECT
    Post.id AS post_id,
    Post.title AS post_title,
    Post.body AS post_body,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Tag.id, "|", Tag.title) SEPARATOR '#') AS tags,
    COUNT(Comment.id) AS comment_count
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Post.id = Comment.id_post
LEFT JOIN Post_Tag ON Post.id = Post_Tag.id_post
LEFT JOIN Tag ON Tag.id = Post_Tag.id_tag
GROUP BY Post.id
ORDER BY Post.date ASC
```

Someone can tell me why I am getting these strange results ( [BLOB - ... ] ) below in the tags column ?

```
id  title           body            tags            comment_count
1   hello guys  blablabla...    [BLOB - 8B]         8
2   hello all   blablabla...    [BLOB - 14B]        3
3   how to tell blablabla...    [BLOB - 8B]         5
4   hello world blablabla...    [BLOB - 5B]         7
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: ok but how can I get the correct results :) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively well-known configuration issue: your `group_concat_max_len` is set to a large value, forcing MySql to use BLOBs instead of `varchar`s for the results of `group_concat`.

To fix, set `group_concat_max_len` to, say, `512` in your `my.ini` or `my.cnf` file, and restart MySql.

Here is a [link to a post with more information](http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/11/why-group_concat-returns-blob/).

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Tag.id, "|", Tag.title) SEPARATOR '#') AS tags,
```

With:

```
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Tag.id, "|", Tag.title) SEPARATOR '#') AS CHAR) AS tags,
```

Documentation: [CAST function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `CONVERT()` and convert BLOB data to `utf8`

```
CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Tag.id, "|", Tag.title) SEPARATOR '#') AS tags USING utf8),
```